# How is it possible to call data from an xml document into an html page?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I'm new to web development but from what I've learned so far, I'm sure what I want to do is super easy. I just haven't quite figured it out, yet.

I have an app that pulls external html pages. These pages all pertain to grain prices. I have about ten pages or so and currently to change the prices I open each page, find the prices and manually change them. What I want to do is just have all the pages pull their prices from the same document (I'm assuming this will have to be an xml or txt document) so that I just have to update that one external document.

The external document will be hosted on the same server as the html pages.

This seems like something I should be able to do simply with javascript and Ajax and I have seen many examples using just that. The thing is that in all of the examples I've seen, the ajax calls an entire text document instead of just one piece of it.

For example, I have an html page called Northern Alberta Prices and it lists about six different grain prices. I want that page to call the external document (let's call it prices.xml) and get all the northern Alberta prices off of it and put them in their proper places on the html page and then I want the Central Alberta Prices page to also call prices.xml and take the relevant prices off it etc.

What would be the best way to do this?

(I'm not able to use PHP on my server at the moment but any answers involving PHP would still be welcome.)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So you aren't using a database or server-side scripting language?  Just producing web pages (with javascript)?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to call the entire document and then interact with the specific node in the XML

without the actual schema there's not much more help I can give you, although there is an ok tutorial here:

http://www.sitepoint.com/server-side-xml-javascript/

which will help you understand the core concepts behind data manipulation

Comment: Thanks. I`ll give that tutorial a look.   That`s right, AlexMA, I`m not using a database or any server-side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to use XML with PHP you can do this:

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

That pretty much says, you can do this:

```
<?php
include 'example.php';

$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

echo $movies->movie[0]->plot;
?>
```

... Which will get the Plot attribute from the first movie node.  Please let me know if you have any additional questions.

Edit:  One more option I came across was using jQuery (javascript):

http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/